# Is this a subgroups of the symmetric group $S_{4}$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I've been given the following question:

"Let $H=\{e, (1 \ 2)(3 \ 4), (1 \ 3)(2 \ 4), (1 \ 4), (2 \ 3) \}$.

Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $S_{4}$"

Every element in this set is contained in $S_{4}$, so it is a subset. Now, we must show that $H$ is closed under the operation, that the elements of $H$ all have inverses contained in $S_{4}$, and that the operation is associative.

If I start by trying to show that $\forall x,y \in H, \quad xy \in H$, we find that $(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4) \circ (1 \ 3)(2 \ 4)=(1 \ 4)(2 \ 3)$. However, $(1 \ 4)(2 \ 3)$ is not in $H$, so it is not closed and therefore not a subgroup.

Is the error in the question, or in my workings?

Comment: My guess is that there shouldn't be a comma between (1 4) and (2 3) in the statement of the question.

Comment: Is your question correct? (check subgroup). What is $|H|$? What is $|S_4|$?

Comment: As it is, $H$ cannot be a subgroup, because $S_4$ has $24$ elements and $H$ has $5$ elements.

Comment: @Groups $|H|=5$ and $|S_{4}|=24|$. How is this relevant?

Comment: Associaton of the operation is not necessary to check, since you know that the operation is associative when considered on any elements in $S_4$. Also, $|G|$ and $|H|$ are relevant because of a theorem carrying the name of Lagrange's theorem. It should be in whatever book you have, because it's important.

Comment: To answer your question: there is no error in your workings so yes there is an error in the question. I believe that Gerry Meyerson's comment above is by far the most likely explanation of what the error in the question is.

Comment: The cardinal of every subgroup must divide the cardinal of the group, and since $5 \nmid 24$ clearly $H \nleq S_4$. Gerry Myerson is probably right in his assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Lagrange's theorem states that the order of the subgroup must divide the order of the group. We know that $|S_n|=n!$, so in our case does the order of the subgroup divide $4!$?